# Background image on :hover does'nt show

Tags: background, hover, css

I'm trying to apply a background image on a menu `li` on a `:hover`, however, it doesn't seem to recognize/show the image. It does respond to a color as background on the hover, which is in the same background line in the CSS.

I've made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pbbpk/) with the code narrowed down to basics:

Obviously the image wouldn't show in this Fiddle, i'm using a local image.

As you can see, it does respond to the background colors, but not to the images.

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: maybe you should use .logo ul li {} in CSS. See http://jsfiddle.net/4cu3s/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works:

```
.logo li:hover
{
    background:navy url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/51/Google.png');
    display: inline-block;
}
```

your doesnt work because you are setting

```
background-image:url('paper.gif');
```

and then you do this:

```
background: navy;
```

this way you are reseting the background canceling previous values

see updated fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/YgxmU/

Comment: Goddamnit, i'm a &#**.

Partially, you are right. However I tried a million combinations, however, I used 'background:transparent url('images/menubg.png');', where as I apparently needed to use 'background:transparent url('../images/menubg.png');'. Hence, it didnt recognize the image on my PC... --

You can tell i'm still quite new to this ;)

Comment: @user2521866 we all are, but every time a little less :)

Comment: @user2521866 hehe two bugs with one debugging :)

Comment: Haha, lets hope so. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You did small mistake following will give your result

```
 background: navy url('paper.gif');
```

Your mistake is you have given as

```
background-image:url('paper.gif');
background: navy;
```

the background property override the `background-image:url('paper.gif');`